# When I reply-all on iPhone, how can I ensure it keeps folks on the To and cc lines?

Tags: email, iphone

I’m using the latest iPhone OS (I believe 8.1.2). When using an Exchange account, sometimes I get mail with multiple people on the “To:” line, and others on the “CC:” line. When I reply all in the mail app, it moves everyone by the sender to the “CC:” line.

For me, this is really annoying as I want to maintain the “To:” line and “CC:” line addresses. Is there an iPhone setting that will cause “Reply All” to respect a mail’s “To:” and “CC:” lines?

Comment: @JakeGould Sorry, I meant 8.1.2 (on an iPhone 6). I've updated the question.